# Creating "altered version of .Offset Function" (or "What would .Offset function look like if it were written in VBA?")

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write an altered variant of VBA's Offset Function, which when a cell is offset by an amount which would ordinarily fall outside of a  specified range, instead takes the number of cells which exceed the range & "wraps" them around from the start of the range again.

I have scoured the net for someone who has written an example of what the .Offset Function would look like if it were written in VBA code, but nobody has done it.

Would anyone mind having a crack at what the .Offset Function would look like in VBA code?

Incidentally, the type of alteration I would be making would be something like this:

```
Public Function MobOffset(off As Integer, REGCOL As Integer)


'The code below is to be used with Range(Cells.Rows(18), Cells.Rows(29))

Rem insert .offset code here:

If off > 29 Then
res = off - 29
off = res - 1 + 18
End If

If off < 18 Then
res = 18 Mod off
res2 = res - 1
off = 29 - res2
End If


End Function
```

Comment: So you want `rng.Offset(off,0)`?

Comment: I only really put the rng part in there as a guide to the range I would be using. Essentially I would be putting in a set relationship of cell.offsets which would be able to rotate "Möbius strip style" around the range(cells.rows(18), cells.rows(29)).

Comment: What is REGCOL here ?  It would help if you could provide a specific concrete example of the behavior you want from this.

Comment: For a rectangular range, `rng.cells(x)` will already work this way, since Excel counts cells across and then down (or "row major")

Comment: An example would be:

with 
    `range(cells.rows(18), cells.rows(29))`
I want 
    `cells.rows(18).moboffset(-2, 0).select`
^where ”-2” is “off” and “0” is “regcol”
to select 
  `cells.rows(28)`

Comment: You need to explain *how* that happens...  Not in code but mechanistically how you arrive at that result.

Comment: It happens via the code in the function above.. where `if off < 18 then res = 18 Mod off
res2 = res - 1
off = 29 - res2
End If`   Mechanistically: 18 - 2 = 16, 18 mod 16 = 2, 2 - 1 = 1, 29 - 1 = 28

Answer (score 0):

The generic formula is

```
count = upper - lower + 1

index = (index - lower) % count + lower
```

so (Mod needs adjustment for negative numbers):

```
off = (off - 18) Mod 12 + 18

If off < 18 Then off = off + 12
```